# Coordino permission issue?

Tags: php, permissions

I put the Coordino in directory `/var/www/namal-geeks.com` and tried to check it on `localhost/namal-geeks.com/` it gives the error

```
Warning: require(app/webroot/index.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in    /var/www/namal-geeks/index.php on line 55

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/webroot/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/namal-geeks.com:/var/www/namal-geeks.com/app/') in /var/www/namal-geeks.com/index.php on line 55
```

I looked in `namal-geeks/index.php` which call the `app/webroot/index.php` and thats what I found there

```
L-No
 41   /**
 42    * Set the include path or define app and core path
 43    */
 44     if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
 45     ini_set('include_path',
 46         ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH
 47     . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS
 48         );
 49     define('APP_PATH', null);
 50     define('CORE_PATH', null);
 51     } else {
 52     define('APP_PATH', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS);
 53     define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
 54     }
 55     require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

Thought it would be problem of permissions so i tried giving the `namal-geeks.com` directory 
`sudo chmod 777 /var/www/namal-geeks.com` but still it gives the same error.

Here is the ouput of the `ls -l` of the directory `www/namal-geeks.com/`

```
total 36
drwx------ 12 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 15 18:59 app
drwx------  6 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 cake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 waqas waqas 1886 Nov 23 19:47 index.php //this file have all permissions 
-rw-r--r--  1 waqas waqas 1053 Apr 19  2013 LICENSE.txt
drwx------  2 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 waqas waqas 4528 Apr 19  2013 Readme.md
-rw-r--r--  1 waqas waqas 3712 Apr 19  2013 README.txt
drwx------  5 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 vendors
```

and here is the output of `ls -l` of the folder`www/namal-geeks.com/app/webroot/` where the other file `index.php` exist and gives error about the permission

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 css
-rwxrwxr-x 1 waqas waqas 2984 Apr 19  2013 css.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 waqas waqas  372 Apr 19  2013 favicon.ico
drwxrwxr-x 2 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 files
drwxrwxr-x 6 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 waqas waqas 2641 Apr 19  2013 index.php //This file causing permissions problems 
drwxrwxr-x 5 waqas waqas 4096 Nov 11 17:00 js
-rwxrwxr-x 1 waqas waqas 5256 Apr 19  2013 test.php
```

I am not sure how to solve this.

Help !

Comment: The actual permissions error seems to have been on a file and not on a folder but you only mention executing `chmod` on the folder (not on the files within). Have you tried taking a look at the existing permissions for the `inex.php` file?

Comment: You shouldn't *really* need to give anything 777 permissions. This is WAY too open normaly. Sure 777 would solve pretty much any permissions problem but then again, you could always leave your front door unlocked - that way no one could (or would need to) break in.

Comment: index.php or inex.php ? file of the project ?

Comment: ahh..yea..sorry. that was a typo..

Comment: can you look at the question again I just updated it. you might understand why its doing that :)

Comment: No - you didn't understand my comments. Check the permissions of the **file** and not of the folder. You shouldn't need to give **anything** 777 permissions.

Comment: It is impossible to read that text within a comment. Perhaps you could add this information to the original post?

Comment: ok i did updated that in question, i used ls -l to see its permissions. or let me know what to use for it

Comment: You'll need to read up on unix permissions - there are entire folders that are unreadable to anyone except your user(waqas)... The `app, cake, plugins, vendors` folders are inaccessible to anyone else. You'll need to give read permissions to all the files needed to run your site.

Answer (score 0):

Is waqas the user defined in your apache.conf?

if not, you can simply

> $chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/namal-geeks/